# Элементых выше главной диагонали заведомо больше чем элементы ниже главной диагонали

Tags: c#

Пусть дана произвольная целочисленная матрица порядка 10. Определите, имеются ли среди элементов, расположенных выше главной диагонали такие, которые превосходят любой из элементов, расположенных ниже главной диагонали. Укажите индексы этих элементов.

```
int[,] A = new int[10, 10];
Random m = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) A[i, j] = m.Next(10);
}
```

Дальше как?

Comment: Дальше нужно считать max элемент ниже главной диагонали, а после этого - искать элементы больше найденного максимума но уже обходя элементы выше главной диагонали. Знак `<=` замените на `<`. И ещё. А что делать в случае если элементов выше(ниже) главной диагонали нет?

Answer (score 0):

Дальше нужно считать max элемент ниже главной диагонали, а после этого - искать элементы больше найденного максимума но уже обходя элементы выше главной диагонали.

```
void Main()
{
    var size = 10;
    var maxVal = 10;
    var nums = Generate(size, maxVal);
    nums.Dump();
    
    for (int i = 1; i < size - 2; i++)
    {
        var max = nums[i + 1, i ];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size - 1; j++)
        {
            if(nums[j, i] > max)
                max = nums[j, i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Элемент главной диагонали: {nums[i, i]}. Max под диагональю: {max}");

        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            if(nums[j,i]>max)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Элемент {j},{i} = {nums[j,i]} больше {max}");
            }
        }
    }
}

// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here

private int[,] Generate(int size, int maxVal)
{
    int[,] result = new int[size, size];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            result[i, j] = rand.Next(maxVal);
    }
    return result;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И ещё. А что делать в случае если элементов выше(ниже) главной диагонали нет?